# SQL Server stored procedure permissions checking

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, permissions

My Asp.Net MVC web-site uses stored procedures based data access to the SQL Server database. Almost every procedure should check permissions, if current user can perform this operation. I've solve it by passing additional parameter `UserId` to every procedure and checking if user has special permission code in special table.

It causes many copy-pasted script. I wonder, is there any another way? Or may be you have an advices to improve my solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, but what if you encapsulate the logic to lookup the permission for the given user and item in a user defined function. Then, invoke the function from the necessary stored procedures and check the return value. You still will wind up with some copying and pasting but in theory it should result in a cleaner approach.

Comment: Ok, I've written a function that returns bit and check it now: IF (dbo.checkPermissions(@UserId, 31) == 1) THEN ... Can I redesign function to make an ability to use it without '== 1' ?

Comment: I don't believe so because the BIT datatype can be one of three values: 0, 1, or null.